# Java newbie - car application

Tags: java

I'm a student and, yes, this is my homework. I've spent the last week reviewing notes, reading the book, and researching related topics on the net, but I just don't get what the problem is. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated. (I'm only using notepad and the command prompt.)

The guidelines I was given: Create a Java application consisting of two classes.  Class one will be your application class.  Class two will be a class called Car. Your application will create an instance of Car, called nova, and drive it.

Rules for the car:

- You can’t drive  a car if it is not started (send an error message to the console).
- You can’t stop a car if it is not started (send an error message to the console).
- You can’t start a car if it is already started (send an error message to the console).
- Once you tell the car to drive, the only thing you can do is stop (Send a message to the console)
- Once you call stop, the car will return to the initial state and the user must start the car before attempting to do any other functions. (Send a message to the console)

The purpose of the showState method is provide a way to inspect the state of the car.  It should build a message, which can then be sent to the console.

My code:

```
public class MyAppAssignment3
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       System.out.println("Scenario 1");
       Car nova1 = new Car();
       nova1.start();
       nova1.showState();
       nova1.drive();
       nova1.stop();
       nova1.showState();
       System.out.println("");

       System.out.println("Scenario 2");
       Car nova2 = new Car();
       nova2.showState();
       nova2.drive();  //needs to send error message - can't drive a car that's not started
       nova2.stop();
       nova2.showState();
       System.out.println("");

       System.out.println("Scenario 3");
       Car nova3 = new Car();
       nova3.showState();
       nova3.start();
       nova3.showState();
       nova3.stop();   //needs to send error message - can't stop a car that's not driving
       nova3.showState();
       nova3.drive();
       nova3.stop();
   }
}

class Car
{
   private boolean isStarted;
   private boolean isDriving;
   private boolean isStopped;
   private String showState;

   public Car()
   {
       this.showState = showState;
   }

   public void start()
   {
       isStarted = true;
       isDriving = false;
       isStopped = false;
       System.out.println("The car is " + this.showState);
   }

   public void drive()
   {
       isStarted = false;
       isStopped = false;
       isDriving = true;
       System.out.println("The car is " + this.showState);
   }

   public void stop()
   {
       isStopped = true;
       isStarted = false;
       isDriving = false;
       System.out.println("The car is " + this.showState);
   }

   public String showState()
   {
       if (isStarted)
       {
           showState = "started";
       }
       else if(isDriving)
       {
           showState = "driving";
       }
       else if(isStopped)
       {
           showState = "stopped";
       }
       System.out.println("The car is " + this.showState);
       return showState;
   }
}
```

My output (which is all wrong - the values are incorrect):

```
Scenario 1
The car is null
The car is started
The car is started
The car is started
The car is stopped

Scenario 2
The car is null
The car is null
The car is null
The car is stopped

Scenario 3
The car is null
The car is null
The car is started
The car is started
The car is stopped
The car is stopped
The car is stopped
```

Sorry if this posted all wonky. I typed it fine but the preview looks screwy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked! Thanks for all the help!

```
public class MyAppAssignment3
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Scenario 1");
        Car nova1 = new Car();
        nova1.start();
        nova1.showState();
        nova1.drive();
        nova1.stop();   
        nova1.showState(); 
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Scenario 2");
        Car nova2 = new Car();
        nova2.showState();
        nova2.drive();
        nova2.stop();
        nova2.showState();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Scenario 3");
        Car nova3 = new Car();
        nova3.showState();
        nova3.start();
        nova3.showState();
        nova3.stop();
        nova3.showState();
        nova3.drive();
        nova3.stop();
    }
}

class Car
{
    private boolean isStarted;
    private boolean isDriving;
    private boolean isStopped;
    private String showState;

    public Car()
    {
        isStarted = false;
        isDriving = false;
        isStopped = true;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        if(isStarted == false)
        {
            isStopped = false;
            isStarted = true;
            showState();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You can't start a car which is already started.");
        }

    }

    public void drive()
    {
        if(isStarted)
        {
            isDriving = true;
            showState();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You can't drive a car which is not started.");
        }

    }

    public void stop()
    {
        if(isStarted)
        {
            isStarted = false;
            isDriving = false;
            isStopped = true;
            showState();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You can't stop a car which is not started.");
        }

    }

    public String showState()
    {
        if(isStarted && (isDriving == false))
        {
            showState = "started";
        }
        else if(isStarted && isDriving)
        {
            showState = "driving";
        }
        else if(isStopped)
        {
            showState = "stopped";
        }
        System.out.println("The car is " + this.showState + ".");
        return showState;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't actually doing anything...

```
public Car()
{
    this.showState = showState;
}
```

Basically, it's simply reassign the same value back to itself.  I'd change to an initial state, probably of `stopped`

I'd use `enum` for my car status, rather then relying on `boolean` states, which could become jumbled...

```
public enum CarState {
    Stopped,
    Started,
    Driving
}
```

Then simply assign it to a single `state` variable...

```
class Car
{
    private CarState state;

    public Car()
    {
       this.state= CarState.Stopped;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        if (state.equals(State.Stopped)) {
            state = CarState.Started;
            showState();
        } else {
            System.error.println("Car is not in a valid state to be started");
        }
    }

    public void drive()
    {
        if (state.equals(State.Started)) {
            state = CarState.Driving;
            showState();
        } else {
            System.error.println("Car is not in a valid state to be driven");
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        if (state.equals(State.Driving)) {
            state = CarState.Stopped;
            showState();
        } else {
            System.error.println("Car is not in a valid state to be stopped");
        }
    }

    public String showState()
    {
        System.out.println("The car is " + state);
    }
}
```

The other issue you're having is that the `showStatus` isn't been called when you change state, which isn't assigning the current state to the `showState` variable...which I've corrected for by using `enum`

Answer (score 2):

For one you're just creating a new instance. You never actually set defaults for those instances.

Consider at least something like this:

```
public Car()
{
    isStopped = true;
}
```

That way when you call your first `nova1.start();` you can check if isStopped is true before allowing it to start again...

```
public void start()
{
    if(isStopped)
    {
        isStarted = true;       
        isDriving = false;       
        isStopped = false;   
        showState = "started";    
        System.out.println("The car is " + this.showState);
    }
}
```

Just one example. But you can easily use that to extrapolate the rest of your needs. My point is primarily that you create an instance but then expect the boolean values to have a value without being specified. You can do this in defaults, or in the constructor.

For example:

```
private boolean isStarted = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using enum's is a nice idea. 
Here is an Implementation using Enum's, Enum's with default Implementations and own implementations using the typesystem.
Also there aren't any Conditionals, like if or switch used.
Just pure and beautiful Java Code.

```
public class Car {
private enum State {
  OFF {
    void start(Car c) {
      System.out.println("Starting the car");
      c.state = State.STARTED;
    }
  }, 
  STARTED {
    void stop(Car c) {
      System.out.println("Stopping the car");
      c.state = State.OFF;
    }
    void drive(Car c) {
      System.out.println("Driving the car");
      c.state = State.DRIVING;
    }
  }, 
  DRIVING {
    void stop (Car c) {
      System.out.println("Stopping the car");
      c.state = State.OFF;
    }
  };

  void start(Car c) {
    System.err.println("Can't start");
  }

  void stop(Car c) {
    System.err.println("Can't stop");
  }

  void drive(Car c) {
    System.err.println("Can't drive");
  }
}
  private State state = State.OFF;

  public void start(){
    state.start(this);
  }

  public void stop(){
    state.stop(this);
  }
  public void drive() {
    state.drive(this);
  }

  public void showState(){
    System.out.println("The car is "+state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is this, each car has its own unique id:

```
 class Car
{
   private boolean isStarted;
   private boolean isDriving;
   private boolean isStopped;
   private String showState;
   private int id;

   public Car(Integer id)
   {
       this.id = id;
   }
...

}
```

then in all place where you say print out, also include id:

```
System.out.println("The car id "+id+" is "+ this.showState);
```

then create an object like that:

```
Car nova1 = new Car(1);

Car nova2 = new Car(2);

Car nova3 = new Car(3);
```

It is not solution, but it gives the way to solution. You will find solution and u will feel it's taste

Answer (score 0):

You have to translate in code what you've been asked for, and as you can see it's even way close to actual requirement - e.g.:

> You can’t drive a car if **it** is **not started** (send an error message to the console).

becomes:

```
public void drive()
{

    if( this.isStarted == false ){

        System.out.println("You should start the car first!");

    }else{

        System.out.println("Car is running!");

    }

}
```

Notice that you can write `!this.isStarted` as a shorthand for `isStarted == false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting the value of variables in each step. There are a few issues in the logical flow. For example, check the constructor.

```
public Car()
{
   System.out.println(showState);
   this.showState = showState;
}
```

There is no showState value being passed to the constructor and its not initialized inside the function too.

Also, inside each function start, stop and drive, you need to write :

```
  System.out.println("The car is " + this.showState());
```

instead of :

```
  System.out.println("The car is " + this.showState);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it simple, why use 3 variables when you need only two? Correct if I'm wrong, but if a car is not started and you are not driving it then it's stopped, right? Look at my class:

```
public class car
{
private boolean isStarted;
private boolean isDriving;

public car()
{
    isStarted = false;
    isDriving = false;
    //Initial State
    showState();
}

public void start()
{
    if(!isStarted)
    {
        if(!isDriving)
            isStarted = true;
    }
    else
        System.err.println("You can\'t start a car which is already started"); //You can’t start a car if it is already started (send an error message to the console).
        showState();
}   

public void drive()
{
    if(isStarted)
        isDriving = true;
    else
        System.err.println("You can\'t drive a car which is not started");

    showState();
}

public void stop()
{
    if(isStarted)
    {
        isStarted = false;
        isDriving = false;
        // Once you call stop, the car will return to the initial state and the user must start the car before attempting to do any other functions. (Send a message to the console. (Below on ShowState)
    }
    else
        System.err.println("You can\'t stop a car which is not started"); // You can’t stop a car if it is not started (send an error message to the console).
    showState(); // Once you tell the car to drive, the only thing you can do is stop (Send a message to the console)
}

public void showState()
{
    if(isStarted && isDriving)
        System.out.println("It\'s Driving");
    if(!isStarted && !isDriving)
        System.out.println("It\'s Stopped");
    if(isStarted && !isDriving)
        System.out.println("It\'s Started");
}

}
```

I hoped it helped. Cheers

Comment: THANK YOU!!! It took awhile, but I pieced together something that works from your replies. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Don't forget to say an answer is correct. It adds you Reputation points and to who answers too. It's a nice way for the site to identify your problem as solved as well